# how do I group layers in QGIS 2.4.0

Tags: qgis, layers

As written in the Title: How do I group layers in QGIS?
I have tried dragging them on top of each other and looked in the layers setting but could not find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the empty space at TOC (Layers), choose `Add group`. Drag and drop layers into the created group.

Answer (score 8):

AndreJ and SS_Rebellious provide valid answers.  However, there is another option which I find easier than creating the group and dragging layers in to it.

You can select all the layers you want in your group (select multiple layers by holding down shift which selects everything between your first selected layer and the second one you click on, or hold down Ctrl to individually add layers to your selection).  When you have several selected, right-click and choose "Group Selected" from the pop-up menu.

The new group tends to end up at the bottom of the pile (if you have a lot of layers that's where you'll find it).

Answer (score 2):

Rightclick on **free** space in the Layer panel -> `Add group`.

This might be cumbersome if you have filled the whole panel with layers. For that reason, an icon bar has been added to the layer panel in the new QGIS 2.6.

Once you have created a group, you can move layers into that group.